# GetStats duration and interval parameters, clarifying API documentation for Jelastic API

Tags: jelastic

https://docs.jelastic.com/api/?class=environment.Control&member=GetStats

At the above link in the Jelastic API documentation for the `GetStats` method there are two parameters `duration` and `interval`.

When querying the api i can't figure out how these two parameters interact with each other.

If i query with the below i would expect 100 records at a resolution of 1 minute

```
/1.0/environment/control/rest/getstats?domain=[myDomiain]&session=[MySession]&duration=6000&interval=60&nodeid=[MyNode]
```

What i get back is 4 records for each hour so i'm unsure of how the parameters work.

Should i be using `GetSumStats`?

My final question would be what format are the `cpu` and `mem` stats in? MHz and Bytes?

```
{
  "iops_used": 0,
  "duration": 3600,
  "cpumhz": 3,
  "start": "2016-05-03 08:00:00",
  "disk": 2141,
  "mem": 194840,
  "cpu": 12254,
  "capacity": 0,
  "net": {
    "in_int": 703019,
    "out_int": 566947,
    "in_ext": 46222,
    "out_ext": 367209
  }
},
{
  "iops_used": 0,
  "duration": 3600,
  "cpumhz": 3,
  "start": "2016-05-03 09:00:00",
  "disk": 2141,
  "mem": 171992,
  "cpu": 10076,
  "capacity": 0,
  "net": {
    "in_int": 156703,
    "out_int": 314023,
    "in_ext": 12627,
    "out_ext": 13535
  }
},
{
  "iops_used": 0,
  "duration": 3580,
  "cpumhz": 3,
  "start": "2016-05-03 10:00:00",
  "disk": 2141,
  "mem": 172400,
  "cpu": 11198,
  "capacity": 0,
  "net": {
    "in_int": 515521,
    "out_int": 551317,
    "in_ext": 10329,
    "out_ext": 17161
  }
},
{
  "iops_used": 0,
  "duration": 3601,
  "cpumhz": 3,
  "start": "2016-05-03 11:00:00",
  "disk": 2141,
  "mem": 172610,
  "cpu": 10032,
  "capacity": 0,
  "net": {
    "in_int": 153394,
    "out_int": 310694,
    "in_ext": 10285,
    "out_ext": 11210
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dlearious, for using **interval** equal 60 you should set **duration** value to 3600. This is due to the fact that Jelastic keeps detailed data hourly.
Also, you can start from minimal **interval** = 20.

Jelastic shows **cpu** in milliseconds and **mem** in Bytes.

Comment: How would i find the average CPU usage and memory usuage for a 4 hour period. Also would GetSumStats be better to use.

Comment: GetSumStats - hourly average data for CPU/Mem/Disk/Network for environment and
GetStats - hourly average data for CPU/Mem/Disk/Network for node.

Comment: Final question, how would I convert CPU milliseconds to average MHz per hour then?

Comment: There is a parameter cpumhz where you can get this data.